# Count amount of files/directories in SELECTED directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting, zsh

I'm trying to make a script that counts files/directories in a specific directory but I have a problem. Here's the script that works for a current directory (count.sh):

```
ARG3=${1:-d} #default value - count directories 
ls -l| grep ^$ARG3 | wc -l
```

I'd love to make a script that works for any directory, not only current one but I have no idea how I could make it. I've searched in google for a long time, unfortunately without success.

The script should be called like:

```
./count.sh  what_to_count(files or dirs)  selected_dir_to_count_in_it
```

Do you have any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
filetype=${1:-d}
find "$2" -type $filetype | wc -l
```

Comment: Oh, it's that simple? Well, thank you :) could you also explain why it counts 1 more directory than I normally see? Is it counting '.' (current dir) as well?

Comment: It's your homework to find out.